# Can't redirect in JSF

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces

This seems silly, but I can not figure out why it is not working, I have the following project tree:

[image]

Inside dashboard.xhtml I have a button that has to redirect the user to RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml.

This is what I tried when using a html button:

```
<button id="reqAbertoBtn" class="btnAcessoRapido" onclick="ClickEvent()">
    <div class="iconeBtnAcessoRapido">
        <i class="fal fa-folder-open"></i>
    </div>
    <span class="tituloBtnAcessoRapido">Requisições em Aberto</span>
</button>  

function ClickEvent() {
    window.location.href = '/evop/protected/compras/requisicao/RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml';
}
```

However the page only refreshed, then I decided to try a PrimeFaces component for that, so I tried:

```
<p:commandButton icon="fal fa-folder-open" iconPos="top" value="Requisições em Aberto" action="/evop/protected/compras/requisicao/RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
```

So when I clicked the button an error saying that it was not possible to find the resource "/evop/protected/compras/requisicao/RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml" occurred, but the page is there, you can access it if you type the url in the browser.

I also tried using outcome:

```
<p:button icon="fal fa-folder-open" iconPos="top" value="Requisições em Aberto" outcome="/evop/protected/compras/requisicao/RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml"/>
```

and

```
<p:button icon="fal fa-folder-open" iconPos="top" value="Requisições em Aberto" outcome="../compras/requisicao/RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml"/>
```

and

```
<p:button icon="fal fa-folder-open" iconPos="top" value="Requisições em Aberto" outcome="RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml"/>
```

Needles to say that also gave me an error:

```
Could not resolve NavigationCase for outcome: /evop/protected/compras/requisicao/RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml
```

I can't believe it is that hard to do a simple page redirect, what am I missing here?

Comment: Almost seems like you are using JSF 1.x ? In JSF 1.x you have to define navigation rules in `faces-config.xml`. If you are unsure - can you show us your classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can give the reference to page RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml W.r.t. DashBoard.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton icon="fal fa-folder-open" iconPos="top" value="Requisições em Aberto" action="../compras/requisicao/RequisicoesEmAberto.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had tried this before it didn't work.